# HTML error checking? Need an extension or baked in?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I noticed that my HTML is not getting validated in VSCode (I have the latest version).

Here is a simple HTML code example:

[image]

According to VSCode, no issues were found after saving the file as index.html. But, I have a misspelled `meta` tag element and a duplicate `body` tag.

You can see that VSCode recognizes the file as being an HTML document.

[image]

[image]

The VSCode official docs states that you can download an HTML extension to help with HTML formatting, but then I read that VSCode now includes a baked-in HTML formatter. There is also the popular ***HTML Snippets*** extension by *Mohamed Abusaid* that the docs recommend but, according to Mohamed, that extension is no longer supported because it conflicts with the *"existing VS Code HTML extension"*.

**Question: What's the correct way to get my HTML validated ? Do I need an extension? Is there an internal setting somewhere? Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extension such as [HTMLHint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkaufman.HTMLHint).